# Django test: how to compare result of resolve() with view function when login_required is specified for that view

Tags: django, django-testing, login-required

In **urls.py** i have my view *detail* annotated with *login_required* to forward unauthorised users to login page:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(views.detail), name = 'detail')
```

And i'm trying to write a test to check which view are selected on querying target url. I've a class to log in before tests start off:

```
class LoggedInTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user('test', 'test@example.com', 'test')
        self.client.login(username='test', password='test')

class ProductDetailTest(LoggedInTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(ProductDetailTest, self).setUp()

    def test_product_detail_url_resolves_product_detail_view(self):
        view = resolve('/products/1/')
        self.assertEquals(view.func, detail)
```

and when i run tests i got:

```
FAIL: test_product_detail_url_resolves_product_detail_view (products.tests.ProductDetailTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\heroku\django\products\tests.py", line 46, in test_product_detail_url_resolves_product_detail_view
    self.assertEquals(view.func, detail)
AssertionError: <function detail at 0x05CC3780> != <function detail at 0x053B38A0>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To check which view are resolved

```
    print('VIEW: ', view.view_name)
```

and result is:

```
test_product_detail_url_resolves_product_detail_view (products.tests.ProductDetailTest) ... VIEW:  products:detail
```

When i remove **login_required** all tests pass well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `login_required(detail)`, the decorator returns a new function. Your assertion should fail in the test, because the functions are not the same.

Here's a couple of options. It might be simplest to use the decorator in the view:

```
@login_required
def detail(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
```

and change the url pattern to:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
```

If you need to use the undecorated `detail` view, then you can't use the decorator like that. In that case, you assign `login_required(detail)` to a new variable,

```
def detail(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

login_required_detail = login_required(detail)
```

change the URL pattern to,

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.login_required_detail, name = 'detail'),
```

and change the test to :

```
self.assertEquals(view.login_required_detail, detail)
```

Comment: Thanks, i suspected this behaviour but i was in doubt if there is some special assertion function to check the  decorated one. Annotating function with @login_required works fine.

Comment: No, there's not a built in assertion that would unwrap the decorated function for you. It looks like it may be possible to [unwrap the decorated function](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch09s03.html) nicely in Python 3. But changing the views/tests as I suggested above is simpler.